# how to toggle class to a single element inside a v-for

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, v-for

I'm new to vueJs and I'm trying to toggle a class "active" to a single element once you clicked on it. Here is my code witch toggle all element with the class material_icons. How to do it to toggle only the element clicked ? 
thanks.
My hmtl :

```
 <div v-for="(listArtist, index) in listArtists" class="col s4 center" id="art">
<p> {{ listArtist.title_short }}</p>
<p>{{ listArtist.artist.name }} </p>
<p>{{ listArtist.album.title }}</p>
<div id="margin-test">   
    <i class="material-icons" @click="fav(listArtist.title,listArtist.album.title,listArtist.artist.name,listArtist.id)"  v-bind:class="{'active': color}">favorite_border</i>
</div>
```

my js :

```
data: {
listArtists:[],
color: false,
}

fav: function(titleTrack, album, artist, id ){
            this.color = !this.color
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is you currently have **only one** `color` flag and multiple artist elements.

To make it work, you have to find a way of having, instead, **multiple** `color`s flags, one for each artist.

You could do it in basically two forms:

- You can declare `color` as an auxiliary object and use `id` as key (demo 1 below).

  - The same would be achieved by making `color` an array and using `index` (of the `v-for`) instead of `id`.
  - The advantage of this approach is not to add any properties to your current artist elements.
- You could also declare a `color` property in each artist and use it instead (demo 2 below).

  - This is somewhat cleaner, but does require the addition of the `color` property.

## Demo 1 (using `color` as a separated object or array)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    listArtists: [
     {id: 1, title: 'title1', title_short: 'title_short1', artist: {name: 'artist.name1'}, album: {title: 'album.title1'}},
      {id: 2, title: 'title2', title_short: 'title_short2', artist: {name: 'artist.name2'}, album: {title: 'album.title2'}}
    ],
    color: {},
  },
  methods: {
    fav: function(titleTrack, album, artist, id) {
      this.$set(this.color, id, !this.color[id]);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(listArtist, index) in listArtists" class="col s4 center" id="art">
    <p> {{ listArtist.title_short }}</p>
    <p>{{ listArtist.artist.name }} </p>
    <p>{{ listArtist.album.title }}</p>
    <div id="margin-test">
      <i class="material-icons" @click="fav(listArtist.title,listArtist.album.title,listArtist.artist.name,listArtist.id)" v-bind:class="{'active': color[listArtist.id]}">favorite_border</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Demo 2 (using a `color` property on each element)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    listArtists: [
     {id: 1, title: 'title1', title_short: 'title_short1', artist: {name: 'artist.name1'}, album: {title: 'album.title1'}},
      {id: 2, title: 'title2', title_short: 'title_short2', artist: {name: 'artist.name2'}, album: {title: 'album.title2'}}
    ],
    color: {},
  },
  methods: {
    fav: function(titleTrack, album, artist, id, listArtist) {
      this.$set(listArtist, 'color', !listArtist.color);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(listArtist, index) in listArtists" class="col s4 center" id="art">
    <p> {{ listArtist.title_short }}</p>
    <p>{{ listArtist.artist.name }} </p>
    <p>{{ listArtist.album.title }}</p>
    <div id="margin-test">
      <i class="material-icons" @click="fav(listArtist.title,listArtist.album.title,listArtist.artist.name,listArtist.id,listArtist)" v-bind:class="{'active': listArtist.color}">favorite_border</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works ! Thanks a lot for your explanation and the code.

Answer (score 1):

One Simple solution:

1. in `@click="fav`, let selectedItem=current selection (=listArtist)
2. then use `v-bind:class="{'active': selectedItem == listArtist}"`

And there is one issue in your codes, you'd better provide [the unique key for each item](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key).

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        listArtists: 
        [
          {id:1,'title_short':'Test-A',artist:{name:'Name-A'}, album:{title:'Title-A'}},
          {id:2,'title_short':'Test-B',artist:{name:'Name-B'}, album:{title:'Title-B'}},
          {id:3,'title_short':'Test-C',artist:{name:'Name-C'}, album:{title:'Title-C'}}        
        ],
        selectedItem: null
    },
    methods: {
      fav: function(listArtist, titleTrack, album, artist, id ){
        this.selectedItem = listArtist
      }
    }
});
```

```css
.active{
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.1/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(listArtist, index) in listArtists" class="col s4 center" :key="index">
  <p> {{ listArtist.title_short }}</p>
  <p>{{ listArtist.artist.name }} </p>
  <p>{{ listArtist.album.title }}</p>
  <div id="margin-test">   
      <i class="material-icons" @click="fav(listArtist, listArtist.title,listArtist.album.title,listArtist.artist.name,listArtist.id)"  v-bind:class="{'active': selectedItem == listArtist}">favorite_border</i>
  </div>
</div>
```